# Calculating Average for a section

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, average

I am creating a Task list, and I have few stages. I have % done. in the picture below I want Cell J8 to calculate the average the to Stage 1 % Done which is between cell J9:J15, however, I want be able to insert a new row below or above row 15 and i want the cell J8 to calculate the average for those too. Hopefully this makes sense,

[image]

Thank you!

I tried to look for appscript code but i couldnt find any,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Apps Script to compute the average

In your use case, I've opted to create a script to calculate the average on column `J`. For reference, here's the script I wrote:

```
/*Script is configured to only run when a specific sheet and the J column is changed.
  This ensures that the script won't randomly trigger if another sheet and/or column is edited. */

function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'sheet_name' && e.range.columnStart == 10) { //replace sheet_name with the name of your sheet
    var indexVal = sh.getRange(9, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 8).getValues().flat().indexOf('Stage 2') + 8; // gets the last row of the value to average
    var aveRange = sh.getRange(`J9:J${indexVal}`).getValues().filter(x => x != ''); // gets the all of the values to average.
    var aveValue = aveRange.reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)) / aveRange.length;
    sh.getRange('J8').setValue((aveValue * 100).toFixed(2) + '%'); //adds the computed average to J8
  } else return; 
}
```

This script gets the last row of the values to average by checking which row `Stage 2` is on then computes the average of all of the values from `J9` up to the row before `Stage 2`. The computed average is then insterted onto `J8`. The script only triggers when a specific sheet and the J column was edited. Be advised, however, that simple triggers won't run when an entire row is deleted.

Also, note that, in order for a simple trigger to work, you would have to bound this script to the spreadsheet.

### References:

- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [Custom Menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Hello Thank you for this, Is there anyway to do it on Edit rather than a custom button? thank you

Comment: Hi @adavoodi. It's possible through the use of `simple triggers`. However, it would be best if the trigger's scope is restricted to specific rows/colums/cells. Otherwise, the trigger will run whenever the script is edited, regardless of whether that edit affects the column in question. Are you manually entering the values on the `J` column or are there specific rows/colums/cells being edited that should trigger the script?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick respond. I am manually entering the value of J column.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my answer based on your requirements and changed the script to an `onEdit` trigger. Feel free to let me know if you have more questions regarding the answer I provided or to accept it (by clicking the checkmark icon beside the answer) if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Im not sure why but im getting NaN% on the J8 cell.

Comment: That happens if there are non-numeric characters, i.e. letters, symbols, or spaces, in the range. I suggest ensuring that the cells from J9 up to the last row of values to be averaged are all numbers in % format.